# Mulesoft RAML - Api specification with request body schema and response body schema on nested XSD file

Tags: xml, xsd, mule, mulesoft, raml

I'm trying to create an API specification with a request body schema and response body schema that referenced two files XSD OTA_CancelRQ.xsd and OTA_CancelRS.xsd

[image]

My problem is that the file OTA_CancelRQ.xsd references two XSD files "OTA_CommonTypes.xsd" and "OTA_SimpleTypes.xsd" with a xs:include string

[image]

If I use this API specification with a project in Anypoint Studio, and call the method OTA_CancelRQ with a XML body request, I have an error that said "Cannot resolve the name 'OTA_PayloadStdAttributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component", but the 'OTA_PayloadStdAttributes' component is contained in "OTA_CommonTypes.xsd" file.

I tried also with the command "xs:import", but the final result is the same "Cannot resolve the name 'OTA_PayloadStdAttributes' to a(n) 'attribute group' component"

My question is: it's possible to create a API specification with XSD schema that referenced another local XSD file?

Comment: no other help for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `<xs:include>` but `<xs:import>` is known to work:

```xml
<xs:import namespace="http://www.somecompany.com" schemaLocation="someschema.xsd"/>
```

I believe that you would see a different error if it were not able to find the issue. I suspect the problem is that the namespace is not the right one.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I tried also with xs:import, but the result is the same (in the namespace field I inserted the value of targetNamespace of the xsd file referenced).